# auto width in Chrome browser is not working

Tags: css, google-chrome

last night I went to my website and found that the css property width: auto in Chrome in not functioning... meaning it has no effect on my css style. Is there a fix that make the width auto fill to a text or image like what used to be in the general css property width?

I was trying many solutions such as adding a fixed width instead, but that causes other styling issues...

any idea what to do?

**Update:**

```css
.userinfo_extra dl dt {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.userstats dt {
  margin-left: 6px;
}
.userstats dd {
  border: 1px dotted #EDEDED;
  margin-left: 3px;
}
.userinfo_extra dl {
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  float: left;
  min-width: 180px;
  width: auto;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FDFDFD;
}
```

```html
<div class="userinfo_extra fwidth">
  <dl class="userstats"> <dt>Join Date</dt> 
    <dd>Apr 2015</dd> <dt>Posts</dt> 
    <dd>210</dd> <dt>eval level</dt> 
    <dd id="reppower">10</dd>
    <dd></dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

[image: This is the screenshot of what I'm trying to do. I want to make the whole code RTL instead of LTR direction]

**This is the screenshot of what I'm trying to do. I want to make the whole code RTL instead of LTR direction as well.**

Comment: You have to show us what have you tried so far, or making a demo will better.

Comment: I have bunch of codes all around. I will post one of them as an example.

Comment: By "make the whole code RTL instead of LTR directio" do you mean you want "Join Date" on right and "Apr 2014" on the left?

Comment: yes@Shuping, That's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to left float position your dl element, and need make sure your dd element rtl direction.

```css
.userinfo_extra dt { /*don't need to left float dl element */
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.userstats dt {
    margin-left: 6px;
}
.userstats dd {
    border: 1px dotted #EDEDED;
    margin-left: 3px;
    direction: rtl; /*make dd element right to left direction */
}
.userinfo_extra dl { /*don't need to left float dl element */
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    min-width: 180px;
    width: auto;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FDFDFD;
}
```

```html
<div class="userinfo_extra fwidth">
    <dl class="userstats"> 
        <dt>Join Date</dt> 
        <dd>Apr 2015</dd> 
        <dt>Posts</dt> 
        <dd>210</dd> 
        <dt>eval level</dt> 
        <dd id="reppower">10</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Comment: I had to change the float direction to left and the direction to ltr in **.userstats dd** to achieve what I want. Thanks for the effort.